# Why do we say "at right angles", not "at a right angle"?

Tags: etymology, expressions, mathematics

If two lines are perpendicular, we say that they are *at right angles*. This expression looks rather clumsy to me, and I'd prefer saying *at a right angle*. Like I would say *intersect at a sharp angle*, and not *intersect at sharp angles*.

1. Why does this expression *at right angles* exist?
2. Is it acceptable to use *at a right angle* instead of *at right angles*?

Comment: I would say *at a right angle* for two Euclidean lines intersecting at a right angle, but such lines do not exist in real life; our world has three dimensions and the joining of two straight things at a corner produces multiple angles depending on which direction you are facing. Can you provide some examples where you see *at right angles*?

Comment: All 4 angles are right angles when one is (at the intersection of two lines).

Comment: For example, "these roads intersect at right angles". Actually, the comment by alwayslearning may be the answer.

Comment: And, just as interestingly, what is 'right' about a right angle ? Is there something inherently 'wrong' with an acute angle ?

Comment: I guess it's right when you are building a home... This may be a question by itself.

Comment: The term 'right angle' is said to be a word-for-word loan (calque) import of the  Latin _angulus rectus_; here rectus means "upright", referring to the vertical perpendicular to a horizontal base line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both *at a right angle* and *at right angles* are fine (and unambiguous) usage when two lines or segments are considered in two dimensions; such as, on a sheet of paper.

*At right angles* is the phrase of choice if there are more angles involved: a line intersects a plane in 3D, three lines intersect at one point in 3D. Thus

> If a straight line be at right angles to a plane, every plane that passes through it is shall be at right angles to that plane.

Proposition XVIII, *Elements of Euclid*, text of Simmons, Cambridge, 1845.

So *at right angles* is a useful an brief way to say that **all the angles involved are right**. It is often used in situations where *at a right angle* would do.

Also, terms such as *perpendicular* and *orthogonal* do a nice job of capturing (unambiguously) either of the notions, the second one also providing part of the etymology story and catering for higher-dimensional generalizations.

Comment: Yes, and this is a good example of how the indefinite article a is closely associated with a plural.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster Unabridged marks *[at right angles](http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/right+angle)* as an adverb in its own right.

The Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary notes that it's perfectly acceptable to use *[at a right angle](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/right%20angle)* instead:

> - A square has four *right angles*.
> - Hold the nail **at a right angle** to the board.
> - The two boards are joined **at right angles** to each other.

As for the etymology of *right angle*, [Ask Dr. Math states](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/61285.html):

> "right" is an adjective that's a native English word, from the
>   Indo-European *reg-* "to move in a straight line." When a weight is
>   attached to the end of a string, the string hangs straight down and
>   forms a line that makes a *right angle* with the ground.